# Getting internal server error trying to create SSO service in Bluemix

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am trying to create a Single-Sign On service in Bluemix but it keeps showing "internal server error" so I am unable to manage and configure the service.

[image]

Comment: This is not a question for SO (about programming). You might want to delete and re-create the service.

Comment: thanks, before I posted I had tried deleting and recreating but got same error.  I tried creating new service today and it worked so it must have been a temporary glitch.